# Spring Batch: one Reader and two different Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using SpringBatch to read an xml file and save it in a database and also in another file.
The object I want to read has the structure OBJECT(name, logicalName, version , key , status).
I want to save all attributes in the database and the name attribute in the file.
For the moment I have created two different steps for this process:
Step 1 -> save to database
Step 2 -> save name attribute to file

My question is how to run these two steps in parallel even if they read the same file?
I tried to use the same ItemReader and a CompositeItemWriter in this case, saving to database is done successfully but all objects are also saved to the destination file and I want only the name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CompositeItemWriter` is the way to go, no need for two steps for that. You would need to write a custom `FieldSetExtractor` that extracts only the attribute you want to write in the file.